# How do I find out how much of my 1TB free monthly allotment I've used in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I feel like there must be some way to figure out how much of [free 1TB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/) is left besides summing up the "bytes processed" amounts for every single query. But I haven't been able to find it anywhere in the console or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not super easy right now. The best way to get the answer is, as you said, to sum up the bytes processed for the queries you've run.

You can get the data via the [BQ jobs.list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list), or you can use [BQ's audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) if that's more convenient. The audit logs can even be queried in BQ, but of course that incurs additional usage. :-)

You can also see your unbilled usage for GCP services via the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/unbilledinvoice). However, this only shows BQ usage from the free 1 TB tier once you've incurred some actual BQ charges (i.e., once you've gone over the 1 TB), which makes it less useful for your particular use case.

Comment: I see entries for "Google Storage -- Download US EMEA", 
"BigQuery -- Active Storage",  and "Google Storage -- Standard Storage US" . Nothing about the data I've processed, because I haven't gone over the 1TB free limit yet. I'm wondering how close I am to that 1TB limit.

Comment: Hmm, you should see an entry for BigQuery Analysis. Perhaps this page won't show anything until you exceed the 1TB limit. I'll see if I can figure out what's going on here...

Comment: It turns out you can't actually see usage until you consume the first 1 TB. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jeremy's answer, you might get that information also directly via the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*` views as I explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510809/413531) to [How can I monitor incurred BigQuery billings costs (jobs completed) by table/dataset in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477907/how-can-i-monitor-incurred-bigquery-billings-costs-jobs-completed-by-table-dat/62510809) based on [How to monitor query costs in Google BigQuery](https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/)

```sql
SELECT 
  (SUM(total_bytes_processed) * 5) / (1024 * 1024 *1024 *1024),
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
```

Please consider the caveats mentioned in the linked answers (caching, region-specific costs per TB, ...)!