# How can I monitor incurred BigQuery billings costs (jobs completed) by table/dataset in real-time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The biggest chunk of my BigQuery billing comes from query consumption. I am trying to optimize this by understanding which datasets/tables consume the most.

I am therefore looking for a way to track my BigQuery usage, but ideally something that is more in realtime (that I don't have to wait a day before I get the final results). The best way would be for instance how much each table/dataset consumed in the last hour.

So far I managed to find the [Dashboard Monitoring](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards) but this only allows to display the queries in flight per project and the stored bytes per table, which is not what I am after.

What other solutions are there to retrieve this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stackdriver logs, you could [create a sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create) with Pub/Sub topic as target for real-time analysis that filter only BigQuery logs like this :

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource" AND
proto_payload.method_name="jobservice.jobcompleted" AND
proto_payload.service_data.job_completed_event.job.job_statistics.total_billed_bytes:*
```

(see example queries here : https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library?hl=en_US#bigquery-filters)

You could create the sink on a specific project, a folder or even an organization. This will retrieve all the queries done in BigQuery in that specific project, folder or organization.

The field `proto_payload.service_data.job_completed_event.job.job_statistics.total_billed_bytes` will give you the number of bytes processed by the query.

Based on [on-demand BigQuery pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) (as of now, $5/TB for **most** regions, but check for your own region), you could easily estimate in real-time the billing. You could create a Dataflow job that aggregates the results in BigQuery, or simply consume the destination Pub/Sub topic with any job you want to make the pricing calculation :

`jobPriceInUSD = totalBilledBytes / 1_000_000_000_000 * pricePerTB`

because 1 TB = 1_000_000_000_000 B. As I said before, `pricePerTB` depends on regions (see : (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing for the exact price). For example, as of time of writing :

- $5/TB for us-east1
- $6/TB for asia-northeast1
- $9/TB for southamerica-east1

Also, for each month, as of now, the 1st TB is free.

Comment: This is just for inserts? jobInsertResponse. How about retrieved?

Comment: What do you mean by `retrieved`? `jobInsert` covers all `SELECT` requests/jobs (query consumption as you asked) as far as I know.

Comment: This is because when you do a `SELECT` query, the result is stored in a temporary dataset, so it's considered as a `jobInsert`. I suggest to try it by yourself :) Run a SELECT query in BigQuery, and look into the logs with the filter I provided.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but I was actually looking for **BigQuery jobs completed**. I found the right syntax from the [sample queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library?hl=en_US#bigquery-filters). Note that there is a difference between `totalProcessedBytes` and `totalBilledBytes` which is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626848/totalbytesbilled-is-different-from-totalbytesprocessed). Perhaps you can update your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Indeed, this can be different for small queries (even if you process 2 bytes, you'll pay for 10MB). I've updated my answer. I did not know about the sample queries for Stackdriver, I'll definitively bookmark this!

Comment: Do you agree that the cost would be: `totalBilledBytes/1000000000000*5`

Comment: I've updated my answer because in fact, price per TB is not the same depending on the region (I've just discovered that).

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*` views because you don't have to set up the stackdriver logging and can use them right away.

Example taken & modified from [How to monitor query costs in Google BigQuery](https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/monitor-query-costs/)

```sql
DECLARE gb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT 1024*1024*1024;
DECLARE tb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT gb_divisor*1024;
DECLARE cost_per_tb_in_dollar INT64 DEFAULT 5;
DECLARE cost_factor FLOAT64 DEFAULT cost_per_tb_in_dollar / tb_divisor;

SELECT
 ROUND(SUM(total_bytes_processed) / gb_divisor,2) as bytes_processed_in_gb,
 ROUND(SUM(IF(cache_hit != true, total_bytes_processed, 0)) * cost_factor,4) as cost_in_dollar,
 user_email,
FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM `other-project.region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER)
)
WHERE
  DATE(creation_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 
  user_email
```

Some caveats:

- you need to `UNION ALL` all of the projects that you use explicitly
- `JOBS_BY_USER` did not work for me on my private account (supposedly because me login email is @googlemail and big query stores my email as @gmail`)
- the `WHERE` condition needs to be adjusted for your billing period (instead of the last 30 days)
- doesn't provide the "bytes billed" information, so we need to determine those based on the cache usage
- doesn't include the "if less than 10MB use 10MB" condition
- data is only retained for the past 180 days
- `DECLARE cost_per_tb_in_dollar INT64 DEFAULT 5;` reflects only US costs - other regions might have different costs - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing
- you can only query one region at a time

Comment: another caveat is that you can only access the jobs for the current user when using the `JOBS_BY_USER` table. I changed this to just `JOBS` and it works for all users of the project.